# Duplicate vba array in transposed manner

Tags: arrays, vba, duplicates

I have an array which I transpose (I already have the code for this) see below. I now wish to adapt the code so that the following can take place.

Each item in the array is duplicated  so for example

Original Array

```
1    5
2    7
3    11
4    15
```

becomes

```
1 1 2 2  3  3  4  4
5 5 7 7 11 11 15  15
```

As I mentioned the code I have does the transposing I just cant work out how to duplicate

```
Public Sub DynamicTranspose1()
Dim I As Variant
Dim J As Variant
Dim transArray() As Variant
Dim numRows As Integer
Dim numColumns As Integer
'—————————————-
'Get rows for dynamic array.
'—————————————-
Do
numRows = I
I = I + 1

 Loop Until Cells(I, "A").Value = ""
'———————————————-
'Get columns for dynamic array.
'———————————————-
I = 0
Do
numColumns = I
I = I + 1
Loop Until Cells(1, Chr(I + 64)).Value = ""
ReDim transArray(numRows - 1, numColumns - 1)
'—————————————————-
'Copy data from worksheet to array.
'—————————————————-
For I = 1 To numColumns
For J = 1 To numRows
transArray(J - 1, I - 1) = Cells(J, Chr(I + 64)).Value
Next J
Next I
maxcol = Split(Cells(1, numColumns).Address, "$")(1)
Range("A1:" & maxcol & numRows).ClearContents
'———————————————————————
'Copy data from array to worksheet transposed.
'———————————————————————
For I = 1 To numColumns
For J = 1 To numRows
Cells(I, Chr(J + 64)).Value = transArray(J - 1, I - 1)
Next J
Next I
End Sub
```

Can someone assist?

Comment: I'm curious why you need to do this. It seems there might be better alternatives, like looping through the array twice or looping through it once, but setting pairs of variables to the same array elements.

Comment: Looping will take to long as its a very large dataset, and this so far is the quickest way for the transpose to happen

Comment: Also i will be selecting certain fields to retrive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just this?

```
Dim arrIn As Variant
Dim arrOut As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long
'Get data from sheet
arrIn = Range("B9:C12").Value 'or wherever your data is located
'Duplicate the data & transpose
ReDim arrOut(1 To UBound(arrIn, 2), 1 To 2 * UBound(arrIn, 1))
For i = 1 To UBound(arrIn, 1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(arrIn, 2)
        arrOut(j, (2 * i) - 1) = arrIn(i, j)
        arrOut(j, 2 * i) = arrIn(i, j)
    Next j
Next i
'now slap it back onto the sheet
Range("G17").Resize(UBound(arrIn, 2), 2 * UBound(arrIn, 1)).Value = arrOut
```

Looping does *not* take long — unless you are looping through cells to read/write data to/from individual cells in the sheet one at a time. This is what you do, and it will indeed take ages.

In the code above, you will notice that I don't do that. I read the entire array at once, and write it all at once at the end; the `.Value` property of `Range` objects will let you do this.

Once the array is read in, looping through it is as quick as it gets.